# How to separate group_concat result in multiple rows using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-concat

My table is as below:

```
create table testing(
    bnum varchar(7)
);
```

and here is the values:

```
insert into testing values
('0547366'),
('0547367'),
('0547368'),
('0547369'),
('0547370'),
('0547371'),
('0547372'),
('0547373'),
('0547374'),
('0547375'),
('0547376');
```

I used the below query:

```
select group_concat(bnum) as nums from testing;
```

and getting the following result:

```
+============
nums
+============
0547366,0547367,0547368,0547369,0547370,0547371,0547372,0547373,0547374,0547375,0547376
+============
```

But I would like to have the following result where I need multiple sets of numbers where 3 numbers in each set separated by comma:

```
+============
nums
+============
0547366,0547367,0547368
+============
0547369,0547370,0547371
+============
0547372,0547373,0547374
+============
0547375,0547376
+============
```

How can I write this query?

Comment: What is the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: Actually my result set is too long and I wanna separate the result where there is 3 numbers in each set. My actual table is more complex so I simplified the table so that everybody can better understand my problem.

Comment: Edit your question accordingly

Comment: Why not handle this in application code

Comment: I can handle it in application code but wanna interested in query first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select GROUP_CONCAT(bnum),@cnt := @cnt+1,concat('a',@cnt1),
    case when MOD(@cnt,3)=0 then @cnt1:=@cnt1+1 end,@cnt1
    from testing,(SELECT @cnt :=0,@cnt1:=0)z GROUP BY @CNT1 ORDER BY@CNT;
```

You can try above query.

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7f7fd/2) is here.

Comment: @Tareq keep it up ..!!